# Why does Raku crash with 'Abort trap: 6' while using Cro on a MacOS Catalina?

Tags: openssl, raku, rakudo, cro

I'm using macOS Catalina and trying to execute a simple command `raku -e "use Cro::HTTP::Route"`. I will get a message `[1] 19228 abort raku` in the Zsh shell or `Abort trap: 6` in the Bash shell. I face the same issue when using an OpenSSL module like `raku -e "use OpenSSL::Stack"`.

```
> raku -v
This is Rakudo version 2019.11-268-g0e4f8351e built on MoarVM version 2019.11-92-gd7b6855d3 implementing Perl 6.d.

> zef info OpenSSL
OpenSSL:ver<0.1.22>:auth<github:sergot>

> zef info cro
cro:ver<0.8.2>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It happens because of the OpenSSL module cannot find `OpenSSL_version_num` function in `libssl.dylib` in the default paths and crashes.

To fix it you need to install `openssl` through `brew` and make a link for `libssl.dylib` library:

```
brew install openssl
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```